# Exiv2: How to print tag values without printing the corresponding filenames

Tags: command-line, images, exif, webp, exiv2

I'm using `exiv2` 0.27.2. I want to print the tag values of multiple `webp` files, but without the filename being printed.

With the following command:

```
exiv2 -g Exif.Image.Artist -Pv *.webp
```

I get the following output:

```
3q2NIGNI_o.webp       tomato
3qAwrJWu_o.webp       orange
3qDZg9vz_o.webp       cantelope
```

I just want the tag name output, without the filename, like so:

```
tomato
orange
cantelope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either post-process the output with a tool like `sed` etc

```
exiv2 -g Exif.Image.Artist -Pv ./*.webp | sed 's/.*\.webp[[:blank:]]*//'
```

or use a loop to pass a single file at a time:

```
for f in  ./*.webp; do exiv2 -g Exif.Image.Artist -Pv "$f"; done
```

or use `exiftool` e.g.

```
exiftool -q -p '$Exif:Artist' ./*.webp
```